# Event Listeners blocking input in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, use-effect

I'm rendering a react component that sends a request on render (as well as when state changes), but also receives user input.

I'm adding an event listener to accept user input, however, it seems like the events are being blocked by the request being sent. Here's a code snippet of what I'm doing. In the body of the component, I return a simple `<Loading/>` indicator when the request is happening.

[image]

To summarize what happens, when the component mounts, I'm unable to capture user input until the request finishes. Further, on subsequent changes to user input, the input is blocked by the request.

Any thoughts here? Or advice on how to debug?

Comment: please post CODE, not pictures of code - but, unless the request has heavy synchronous loops or something, they will never *block* anything

Comment: heavy synchronous loops? What does that mean? (Also, reproducing the code right now,  pulling up code now, sorry about that).

For context, this request takes a very long time in some cases (a matter of seconds). Could this warrant the issue?

Comment: whatever happens in the *request* ... can't see it from that picture ... something like `for(i=0; i< 100000000000; i++) { do something }` ... that would be bad - but as I said, can't see what the request handling is

Comment: What's the difference between a request that takes 10 milliseconds and 40 seconds? Why would this affect the situation? In both cases, shouldn't the request be scheduled asynchronously or something?

Comment: yes ... and no ... as I can't see how the request response is handled, I can only assume that it's doing a lot of synchronous work - that may explain the symptoms you describe

Comment: can you reproduce it in a sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

@Jaromanda X was correct in the thread above. In the render of my function component, when parsing the returned data (something like `data.map()`), I was making expensive cpu-bound calls. Pagination or caching the data will do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

In functional components, you can think function body as the render() method of old class components. So, when you try to send api request in there, it blocks the rendering of the element. You should make api call in an useEffect() function. So, it will work after component mounted without blocking it.